# Getting user input count

Tags: java

I am writing a program in which the random method generates a random number between 1 and 100, and then the user guesses what the number is. 
Everything in the code I built works fine so far, except the part where the program also calculates the number of user guess attempts.

I know the general idea of how to get the user attempt count: create a count-tracking variable and then increment it with each user entry. Now matter how or where I apply the count-tracking variables, the number of user attempts is always 2, even though there are far more actual attempts. I Googled this issue, and tried different ideas from results (ex: put count++ into every "if/else" statement), but nothing works. 
Can anyone tell what is wrong with my code, and why it is always showing 2 as number of user attempts? Thank you in advance for any help.

```
System.out.println("Enter a number between 0 and 100: ");
int randomDigit = (0 + (int) (Math.random() * 101));

while (true) {
    Scanner scr = new Scanner(System.in);
    int guess = scr.nextInt();
    int guessCount = 0;
    guessCount++;
    guessCount = guessCount + 1;
    if ((guess < 0) || (guess > 100)) {
        System.out.println("You entered an invalid number. \nPlease enter a valid number.");
    } else if (guess > randomDigit) {
        System.out.println("Your guess is too high. \nPlease enter another guess.");
    } else if (guess < randomDigit) {
        System.out.println("Your guess is too low. \nPlease enter another guess.");
    } else if (guess == randomDigit) {
        System.out.println("Congradulations, you found the number!      It is " + randomDigit
                + ".\nThe number of attempts it took you to guess the correct answer is: " + guessCount + ".");
        break;
    }
}
```

The above code always has 2 as number of user attempts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move this line:
int guessCount = 0;
Outside the loop, as you are constantly repeating the initialization of the variable, and thus, not actually counting it. 
When you use a counter, always define it outside your while/for loops.
Good luck

Comment: that worked! You taught me a good Java lesson today :) Thank you!